# Difference between public interface and abstract interface?

Tags: java

Can anyone tell me difference between specifying interface public and abstract?

```
public interface Test{}
```

and

```
abstract interface Test{}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as abstract interface in Java since that's their default behavior.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza There are *only* abstract interfaces.

Comment: @arshajii *since that's their default behavior*

Comment: In fact their only behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The former is an interface that can be accessed from anywhere. The latter (since abstract is [superfluous](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html)) is an interface that can be accessed within the same package, as it has default access modifiers.

Comment: Thanks HexaFraction ..Got it

Comment: And don't forget to upvote answer that is **correct** and of your satisfaction.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi What? To whom are you saying this?

Comment: @hexafraction, I was speaking to prarane.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi He/she does not have 15 rep necessary for voting.

Comment: Thanks, understood! Bear in mind that, in future, he/she might forget to vote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are implicilty abstract. So `abstract interface` is not needed.

From JLS : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.1.1

> 9.1.1.1. abstract Interfaces
>
> Every interface is implicitly abstract.
>
> This modifier is obsolete and should not be used in new programs.

Answer (score 0):

It is redundant to declare an interface as `abstract` as they are all `abstract` by definition. The only difference, then, is the `public` component. Your first interface (which is public) can be accessed from anywhere whereas your second (which has default visibility) is package-private, meaning it can only be accessed within its own package.

Comment: Exactly same?? There is no `public` in `abstract` one..

Comment: @RohitJain I was referring to the `abstract` component, but I will edit to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

`public abstract interface` means it will be available in all the packages. But `abstract interface` will only be available in the current package because of the default access. Read more about access specifiers here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

And packages are abstract by nature, which means they cannot be isntantiated. And all the methods in the package will be abstract. Having the purely abstract method, mandates an implementing class to override them.

Answer (score 0):

As always, the JLS provides the answer ([JLS 9.1.1.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html)):

> Every interface is implicitly abstract.

Of course, I'm assuming that you mean to include the `public` modifier on your second example.  If you don't, then there are other differences between the two -- but they do not relate to the `abstract` keyword.